# Merge data frames where entry is NA

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two data frames and want to merge them by id, so that the value NA in the target data frame "df1" replaced by the value of "df2". Till now I use

```
df1<-data.frame(id=1:3,a=c(NA,"A","B"))
df2<-data.frame(id=1:3,a=LETTER[1:3])
idx<-is.na(df1)
df1[idx]<-df2[idx]
```

But this will not work if the data frames have different dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

In 2 steps using `merge` and `ifelse`:

```
df1<-data.frame(id=1:3,a=c(NA,"A","B"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2<-data.frame(id=1:3,a=LETTERS[1:3],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mm <- merge(df1,df2,by=1,all.y=TRUE,al.x=FALSE)
mm$a.x <- ifelse(is.na(mm$a.x),mm$a.y,mm$a.x)
mm
  id a.x a.y
1  1   A   A
2  2   A   B
3  3   B   C
```

Ore one liner solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(df1,key='id')
DT2 <- data.table(df2,key='id')
DT1[DT2][,list(id,ifelse(is.na(a),a.1,a))]
   id V2
1:  1  A
2:  2  A
3:  3  B
```